# Collect data by grouping data in different tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two different tables.
I group them both within themselves.
there are two columns in both.
So I would like to collect the data in those fields by grouping the same field in two tables.

example;

mytable

```
salarytype    salary
Asalarytype   1000
Bsalarytype   2000
Csalarytype   3000
```

mytable2

```
salarytype    salary
Asalarytype   100
Bsalarytype   100
Csalarytype   100
```

I want : 1000+100=1100 , 2000+100=2100, 3000+100=3100 ...

```
SELECT salarytype
,SUM(salary) FROM mytable GROUP BY salarytiype


SELECT salarytype
,SUM(salary) FROM mytable2 GROUP BY salarytiype
```

the result I want to achieve
;

```
salarytype    totalsalary
Asalarytype    1100
Bsalarytype    2100
Csalarytype    3100
.
.
.
```

Comment: UNION ALL the tables. GROUP BY the result. SUM().

Comment: but I will collect the tables according to their salary types.
@jarlh

Comment: Which database?

Comment: Oracle @mkRabbani

Comment: SELECT salarytype
,SUM(salary) FROM mytable GROUP BY salarytiype
UNION
SELECT salarytype
,SUM(salary) FROM mytable2 GROUP BY salarytiype  ;  I'm doing this. This time I have to group salary types among themselves. how can I do?
@jarlh

Comment: Look at mkRabbani's answer below. Exactly what my first comment suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you desired result -

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT salarytype,
           salary 
    FROM MyTable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT salarytype,
           salary 
    FROM  MyTable2
)
SELECT salarytype,
       SUM(salary)
FROM CTE       
GROUP BY salarytype
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
SELECT salarytype,SUM(Salary) 
FROM
(
    SELECT salarytype,Salary FROM MyTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT salarytype,Salary FROM MyTable2
)A
GROUP BY salarytype
```

Comment: What error? Anyway, you should specify the selected columns, i.e. `SELECT salarytype, salary FROM ...`,

Comment: I want;

In mytable and mytable2, they will group salarytypes into themselves and return two results. Then he will collect the salary from two grouped tables and group again. ? @jarlh

Comment: No need to do several GROUP BY. Simply UNION ALL the selects, and GROUP BY its result. Same result, less to write.

Comment: Please write down the code. Very useful for me
 @jarlh

Comment: Updated the query with specified column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
select salarytype,
       salary+(select salary from mytable2 where mytable2.salarytype== mytable.salarytype)
from mytable;
```

Comment: This does not happen. Because I have two columns of my tables (groupby). @Zabi

Answer (score 0):

I think Your table has duplicate values : so you can do like this

```
select distinct t1.salarytype, sum(t1.salary) from
(
select salarytype, sum(salary) from  mytable GROUP BY salarytype
UNION ALL
select salarytype, sum(salary) from  mytable2 GROUP BY salarytype
) t1
group by t1.salarytype, orderby t1.salarytype

##Hope this will resolve your problem, you can use distinct, to remove 
duplicates
```